# How to setup stomp_interface for failover node for cassandra Opscenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, cassandra-2.1

How to setup a fail-over node for Cassandra Opscenter. The Opscenter data is stored on Opscenter node itself. So to setup a failover node i need to setup an Opscenter different from current Opscenter and sync Opscenter data and config files between Opscenters.

The stomp_interface on nodes in the cluster are pointed towards Opscenter_1 how will it change automatically to Opscenter_2  when failover occurs??

Answer (score 0):

There are steps on the [datastax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/configure/enableFailover.html) that have details for doing this. At a minimum:

1. Mirror the configuration directories stored on the OpsCenter primary to the OpsCenter backup using the method you prefer.
2. On the backup OpsCenter in the failover directory, create a primary_opscenter_location configuration file that indicates the IP address of the primary OpsCenter daemon to monitor

The `stomp_interface` setting on the agents gets changed (address.yaml file updated as well) when failover occurs. This is why the documentations recommend making sure there is no 3rd party configuration management on it.

Comment: Hai Chris thanks for the answer, i am seeing this error on one of the nodes but rest of the 5 nodes got connected.                                                                                      ERROR: Agent for xx.200.163.23 was unable to complete operation (http://xx.200.163.23:61621/failover-stomp?id=ca381315dc3e4341b61a72ad4f282750): No cassandra connections available                                       
INFO: Automatic agent setup failed for (unknown ip): No cassandra connections available (xx.200.163.23)

Answer (score 0):

3 things :

- If you have firewall on, allow the corresponding ports to communicate (61620,61621,9160,9042,7199)
- always verify IF the cassandra is up and running, so agent can actually connect to something.
- stop the agent, check again the address.yaml, restart the agent.